# Get String[] from the other class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-resources

This is my main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

Context con;

protected void onClickCityBreak(View v) {

    String [] arrayCityBreak = con.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citybreak);
    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTo.class);
    myintent.putExtra("PLACES",arrayCityBreak);
    startActivity(myintent);
}
}
```

And this is the class i want to send myintent array to:

```
public class ActivityTo extends ListActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] arrayCityBreak = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("PLACES");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCityBreak = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCityBreak);

    ListView myview = getListView();

    myview.setAdapter(adapterCityBreak);

}
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ActivityTo">

    </activity>
```

I can't find the problem in this. My application shuts down when i click the button to get to the new intent. It is because of the String[] i try to send, but I don't see why is won't work.

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.ivarrreyna.assignment, PID: 2626
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                  at com.ivarrreyna.assignment.MainActivity.onClickCityBreak(MainActivity.java:24)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Application terminated.

Comment: post your error log

Comment: @JyotmanSingh, `Context con = getActivity();` works for `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass array to  , since `ActivityTo` is also an activity so can fetch the resources array here too

```
public class ActivityTo extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String [] arrayCityBreak = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citybreak);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCityBreak = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCityBreak);

        ListView myview = getListView();

        myview.setAdapter(adapterCityBreak);

    }
}
```

---

To remove current error,

either do this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    con=this;
}
```

or

use this in `MainActivity` because `con` is not initialized

```
  String [] arrayCityBreak = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citybreak);
```

instead of

```
  String [] arrayCityBreak = con.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citybreak);
```

Comment: Hi, yeah, but I have more arrays in strings.xml, so if I want to get the other arrays depending on the array i want get from there, i have to create java-files for everyone of them

Comment: @guliing then use the other the other part of my answer

Comment: @guliing you should add more details to clarify your requirements in your post

Comment: @guliing Create Java files for what? You're getting XML string arrays. As mentioned, `getResources()` is accessible from all Activities. So you do not need to pass around extras

Comment: Yeah, I am new to this. But thanks alot, your other answer worked perfectly!

Comment: @guliing little info , you can pass some `int` values to another activity and on the bases of `int` value , you can fetch resources array in other activity using `conditional statements`, instead of passing whole array and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

> My application shuts down when i click the button to get to the new intent. It is because of the String[] i try to send, but I don't see why is won't work.

It is caused by this `con`, because the context is null:

```
Context con;
```

Use this like:

```
String [] arrayCityBreak = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citybreak);
```

or

```
String [] arrayCityBreak = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citybreak);
```